# Curl POST is executed as a GET

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to develop a kind of Browser with `PHP`.
So far my `class` can process a `GET` or a `POST` request with this `Content Type`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Now I need to move to a `JSON` one. I've set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

The fact is, with this type I got the following issue: **Setting up a POST request will result in a GET request**. This is really weird.

Here is my code:

```
private function request($url, $reset_cookies, $post_data = null, $custom_headers = null)
{       
    // Create options
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL               => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER            => 0,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT       => 1,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR       => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT         => $this->user_agent,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT    => 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    => 1,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER       => 1,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION     => $reset_cookies ? 1 : 0,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR         => $this->cookies_file,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        => $this->cookies_file,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER        => array('Accept-language: en'),

        // SSL
        /*
        CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST   => 'TLSv1',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => 1,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO            => dirname(__FILE__) . '/Entrust.netCertificationAuthority(2048).crt',
        */
    );

    // Add headers
    if (isset($custom_headers)) $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array_merge($options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER], $custom_headers);

    // Add POST data
    if (isset($post_data))
    {
        $options[CURLOPT_POST]          = 1;
        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]    = is_string($post_data) ? $post_data : http_build_query($post_data);
    }

    // Attach options
    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $options);

    // Execute the request and read the response
    $content = curl_exec($this->curl);

    print_r($options);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));

    // Clean local variables
    unset($url);
    unset($reset_cookies);
    unset($post_data);
    unset($custom_headers);
    unset($options);

    // Handle any error
    if (curl_errno($this->curl))
    {
        unset($content);
        throw new Exception(curl_error($this->curl));
    }

    return $content;
}
```

To illustrate my issue, here is an example:

`CUrl` options as an `Array`:

```
Array
(
    [10002] => http://mywebsite.com/post/
    [19913] => 1
    [42] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [45] => 1
    [10018] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
    [78] => 30
    [13] => 30
    [52] => 1
    [68] => 10
    [58] => 1
    [96] => 0
    [10082] => C:\wamp\www\v2\_libs/../_cookies/14d0fd2b-9f15-4ac5-8fae-4246cc6cef49.cookie
    [10031] => C:\wamp\www\v2\_libs/../_cookies/14d0fd2b-9f15-4ac5-8fae-4246cc6cef49.cookie
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => Accept-language: en
            [1] => RequestVerificationToken: 4PMxvJsQzFJ5oFt3JdUPe6Bp_geIj4obDJCYIRoU09PrrfcBSUgJT9iB3mXnGFc2KSlYrPcRHF7iHdQhGNu0GKLUzd5FywfaADbGS8wjhXraF36W0
            [2] => Content-Type: application/json
        )

    [47] => 1
    [10015] => {"usernameOrFeedId":"manitoba","feed_message_body":"Dummy message goes here"}
)
```

So the request header seems good to me, but I may be wrong.

And here is the `real` header sent by `CUrl`:

```
GET /post/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Host: mywebsite.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mywebsite.com/post/
Cookie: ADRUM_BT=R%3a53%7cclientRequestGUID%3a9787a51b-b24d-4400-9d6a-efbd618c74c0%7cbtId%3a18790%7cbtERT%3a44; CSRFToken=o_eoIVji7pWclOsrLaJpZEbOFSBJBm851rHbH0Xqwdzw2tC5j07EAc23mlj-opWowgpj0RkHyiktl1cS6onBqI43afM1; WebSessionId=3aem0m2xpwmvesgphna5gaop; prod=rd101o00000000000000000000ffff0a5a2a74o80; AuthenticateCookie=AAAAAtsQgeb8+UXrJ+wa7CGVJKnqizEAo2bMuFvqvwYMAl1NRaa6z68LBRx9hiHzPBC8tYqiayHID6pHChGXB7VywemwTpGivcRQ3nRlUVuaYQKyxQt21p1mx7OMlLCsRA==; web_lang.prod=fr
Accept-language: en
RequestVerificationToken: 4PMxvJsQzFJ5oFt3JdUPe6Bp_geIj4obDJCYIRoU09PrrfcBSUgJT9iB3mXnGFc2KSlYrPcRHF7iHdQhGNu0GKLUzd5FywfaADbGS8wjhXraF34W0
Content-Type: application/json
```

As you can see, it's a `GET` request and the post data look to have disapeared.

Am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're following redirects, that means you get a 3xx response code and curl makes a second request to the new URL.

curl will act according to the specific 3xx code and for some of the redirects it will *change* request method from POST to GET - enabling VERBOSE will show you if it does so or not. The response codes that makes curl change method are 301, 302 and 303. It does so because that's how browsers act on those response codes.

libcurl offers an option called [CURLOPT_POSTREDIR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.html) that you can use to tell curl to *not* change method for specific HTTP responses. Using that, you can thus have curl send a POST even after redirecting with one of these response codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
```

seems to be the cause shown by

```
Referer: http://mywebsite.com/post/
```

seems the server is doing a PRG ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Hello @Exussum, I confirm the server is doing a PRG. How could I fix it ? I can't edit the server code as it's not mine nor accessible.

Comment: The server will always reply with a new location, you can choose not to follow it. The post has happened both ways. the second way the last action (and the one curl is reporting) is the GET. but the POST also did happen

Answer (score 1):

Disable follow location by setting it false and remove the curlopt_maxredirs from your code.

```
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    => false,
    // CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The problem is I can't remove this setting as there is a redirection on the server (which is not mine and I can't edit code on).